# After redirect to a route it immediatly going to the previous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-navigation

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Log/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/result" element={<Result/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/payment" element={<Payment/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/bgmi" element={<Bgmi/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/freefire" element={<Freefire/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/newuser" element={<Newuser/>}></Route>      </Routes>
```

WHEN I TRY TO REDIRECT FROM LOG TO HOME PAGE,IN FEW SECONDS IT RETURN BACK TO THE LOG PAGE

```
 const luname = useRef(null);
  const lpass = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let ak = false;
  const nu = () => {
    navigate("/newuser");
  };
  const nh = async () => {
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:3500/log", {
        luname: luname.current.value,
        lpass: lpass.current.value,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("permission", res.data);
        if (res.data === "access") {
          console.log(res.data);
          ak = true;
        }
      });
    if (ak) {
      navigate("/home");
    }
  };
```

I MAKE A REQUEST TO BACKEND TO GET ACCESS PERMISSION,IF THE PERMISSION IS GRANTED IT REDIRECT TO ANOTHER PAGE,BUT HERE THE CONDITIONS ARE WORKS PROPER THOUGH IT RETURN BACK TO THE PREVIOUS PAGE`your text`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.